# Firebase data messages that work on android and iOS

Tags: firebase, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, android-notifications

Im sending push notifications to both Android and iOS devices...
I'm using [data messages as I want need custom key value pairs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#notifications_and_data_messages) and I need to use them when the [app is in the background](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37845174/66975)

my payload is something like:

```
{
   "to": "device token here",
   "content_available":true,
   "priority":"high",
   "data": {
      "key1": "value1",
      "key2": "value2",
      "key3": "value3",

  }
}
```

This works fine on Android, and notifications come through,  on iOS a notification does not come through...It only comes through if i **include notification** in the payload like so:

```
{
   "to": "device token here",
   "notification": {
     "title": "test",
     "text": "MY Test"

   },  
   "content_available":true,
   "priority":"high",
   "data": {
      "key1": "value1",
      "key2": "value2",
      "key3": "value3",

  }
}
```

The problem with the second approach is that the notification no longer a data message, so I can't work with it when the app is in the background on android...
How can I solve this - i need notifications to work on both platforms, sending data pairs, and ideally even when the app is in the background